# How to get Id value in jquery ajax response?

Tags: jquery, django

In a Django app, I'd like to get ID value in ajax response:

the views.py

```
def like_piccomment(request, cid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        the_comment = PicComment.objects.get(id= cid) 
        the_photo = the_comment.pic
        who_liked = request.user.id

        if PicCommentLike.objects.filter(liker=who_liked, liked=cid):
            the_comment.likes -=1
            the_comment.save()
            PicCommentLike.objects.filter(liker=who_liked, liked=cid).delete()

        else:

            the_comment.likes +=1
            the_comment.save()
            newliker = PicCommentLike(liker=who_liked, liked=cid)
            newliker.save()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['likes'] = the_comment.likes
    args['cid'] = cid
    return render_to_response('userpics/likes.html', args)
```

likes.html

```
{% if likes > 0 %}
{{likes}} 
<i id="{{cid}}">liked</i>
{% else %}
<i id="{{cid}}">No one liked yet</i>
{% endif %}
```

and pass the ajax response to this jquery likeSuccess function:

```
<script>

//ajax send function which works fine

//deal with ajax response
function likeSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //these lines don't work    
    var cid = $(data).find("#id").text(); 
     $('#'+ cid).html(data);

    alert("dom id:" + cid); //just to check }

</script>
```

The difficulty is to grab the ID value from template so that the ajax response appear only on relevant id.

I am noob in jquery and tried many different solutions and none worked. Appreciate your hints.

Comment: You need to show your Django view code that processes the ajax post.

Comment: @Brandon I added the views though it was not needed as the 'cid' is passed just fine to the template.

Comment: What are you asking then? You said cid was not passed to the template, now you're saying it is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry, hopefully I disambiguated my explanation. The problem is with parsing ajax response. The django part is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference check this http://jsfiddle.net/imvinay/eqjes7ua/...

I have recently come across problem like this ... but i used post method of jquery.

From views you can create responses and send it like following

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': 'success','something':'message'}))
```

jquery will go something like this

```
  $(".likecomment").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var cid = $this.attr('id');
         $.post('/pic/like_comment'+cid, $(this).serialize(), function(data){
                result = JSON.parse(data); 
                if(result.message == 'success')
                {
                    yourfunction();
                }

         });
});
```

Comment: This is interesting, but as my views is based on post and I'm not sure how to deal with serialize csrf etc, I'd rather stick to my own clunky way of doing it and just solve the jquery parse issue.

Comment: @HadeS You are correct. The OP needs to be looking for `#{{ cid }}` since that value will have been assigned to the `id` attribute of the `<i>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the point made by HadeS, I manage to solve the problem by minimum hassle like this:

likes.html

```
<i title="{{cid}}">
{% if likes > 0 %}
{{likes}} Liked
</i>
{% else %}
No one liked yet
</i>
```

and in jquery function:

```
function likeSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
     var cid = $(data).attr('title')
     $('#'+ cid).html(data);
}
```